# Kubernetes finding logs of a failed cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I found a failed cronjob in my Kubernetes cluster running on Google GKE. I only have information about the failure state and failure reason of the job.

Although I located the failed job and learned that it reached the backoff limit, I would like to access the actual logs or stdout of the pod to identify the code error that caused the failure.

However, when I tried to use a command to check the log, I discovered that the pod had already been deleted, and I could not locate the failed pod.

But from GKE UI, I can found there are logs showing errors in my code and the information is what I am looking for.

I am wondering whether it is GKE implementing a logging system so I can find the logs?

Because I found the following information in the doc:

> Note: If your job has restartPolicy = "OnFailure", keep in mind that your Pod running the Job will be terminated once the job backoff limit has been reached. This can make debugging the Job's executable more difficult. We suggest setting restartPolicy = "Never" when debugging the Job or using a logging system to ensure output from failed Jobs is not lost inadvertently.

Does this mean that if my job's restartPolicy is set to OnFailure, the corresponding pod will be deleted upon failure, and there will be no way to check the pod's logs?

Did I find logs in GKE because it has its own logging system, or is there another action I can take to access these logs?

Thanks.

Following is the snippet of my cronjob.

```
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          containers:
          - command:
            - $cmd
            image: $img
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: $job_name
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: 0 4 * * *
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CronJobs have a history value:

`.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit`

Set these to how many successful/failed jobs you wish to keep, and Kubernetes will keep that many failed or successful pods. I generally keep 3 failed, 1 successful, but if debugging, I'll keep more (6 failed, 3 successful)

---

Edited version of your yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          containers:
            - image: busybox
              # command:
              # - $cmd
              command:
                - "sh"
                - "-c"
                - "exit 1"
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: crontest
              resources: {}
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: 0 4 * * *
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
```

I was able to reproduce your issue with this. I saw this message in logs:

```
Events:                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│   Type     Reason                Age    From            Message                                                                                                                            │
│   ----     ------                ----   ----            -------                                                                                                                            │
│   Normal   SuccessfulCreate      9m26s  job-controller  Created pod: my-app-manual-xnj-fpvzq                                                                                               │
│   Normal   SuccessfulDelete      3m18s  job-controller  Deleted pod: my-app-manual-xnj-fpvzq                                                                                               │
│   Warning  BackoffLimitExceeded  3m18s  job-controller  Job has reached the specified backoff limit                                                                                        │
│
```

Change your yaml to change the `restartPolicy`:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          containers:
            - image: busybox
              # command:
              # - $cmd
              command:
                - "sh"
                - "-c"
                - "exit 1"
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: crontest
              resources: {}
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Never ### <--- this is changed
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: 0 4 * * *
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
```

Then produces this:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-manual-29l-27x8v   0/1     Error    0          2m9s
my-app-manual-29l-64th2   0/1     Error    0          110s
my-app-manual-29l-shfk7   0/1     Error    0          2m4s
my-app-manual-29l-tj9k7   0/1     Error    0          84s
my-app-manual-29l-tzlwd   0/1     Error    0          40s
```

So in short, yes, the `restartPolicy` is the reason you're not seeing the failed pods.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked my cronjob config. Both `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and  `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` are set to 3.
From the job (kubectl get jobs), I can see the failed job and this is where I found  my cronjob fails sometimes.
However, I cannot find the failed pods , all the pods left are successfully executed pod.

Comment: Is it possible to share your CronJob yaml as a Gist or pastebin (you can redact anything confidential if needed) -- this will allow others to check and replicate your issue.

Comment: From the failed job description, what I can find is that the job is viewed as failure due to reaching backoff limit.
There's no other clues, and that leads to my confusion.

Comment: Yes, but if others can reproduce the problem, we may be able to determine what is incorrect. My initial hunch is that you maybe have set `restartPolicy: OnFailure` which is causing the job to restart when it fails, without failing the job run; until the retry limit is reached, and then the entire job to be marked as failed.

Comment: I pasted the snippet of my CronJob yaml, if something missing of lack of information, just let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: I have replicated your problem and proposed some edits for you. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. 
That way, I need to reset my restartPolicy to keep the failed pods or to have a log system to track debugging info.
Really appreciate the information you provided!

Comment: You can (and should) have both -- you can have both the failed pods *and* have a log system (ELK, StackDriver, etc.)  You can check the logs quickly using the failed pods option, but then still have the backup option of querying against a log database for more complex queries.

Comment: `> Then produces this:` These are pods, not logs, question asked for logs.

Comment: @goulashsoup the question asked for FINDING logs. The logs could not be found initially, because the pods were not being kept. The fact the pods were present now, does answer the question, as the OP indicated by accepting the answer.

Comment: `> The fact the pods were present now, does answer the question` No it does not, OP accepted an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Does this mean that if my job's restartPolicy is set to OnFailure, the corresponding pod will be deleted upon failure, and there will be no way to check the pod's logs?***

In general, all the logs related to the pod will be lost once the pod gets deleted. The reason is simple, by default all the logs will get saved to the pod's volume and these volumes get deleted once the pod gets deleted as mentioned in the [kubernetes official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#:%7E:text=On%2Ddisk%20files%20in%20a%20container%20are%20ephemeral%2C%20which%20presents%20some%20problems%20for%20non%2Dtrivial%20applications%20when%20running%20in%20containers.%20One%20problem%20is%20the%20loss%20of%20files%20when%20a%20container%20crashes.%20The%20kubelet%20restarts%20the%20container%20but%20with%20a%20clean%20state.).

> On-disk files in a pod are ephemeral, which presents some problems for
> non-trivial applications when running in pods. One problem is the loss
> of files when a pod crashes. The kubelet restarts the container but
> with a clean state.

***Did I find logs in GKE because it has its own logging system, or is there another action I can take to access these logs?***

Cloud Providers like Google Cloud Platform(GCP) will enable features like [logging and monitoring by default](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke#:%7E:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20GKE%20cluster%20running%20on%20Google%20Cloud%2C%20Cloud%20Logging%20and%20Cloud%20Monitoring%20are%20enabled%20by%20default%20and%20provide%20observability%20specifically%20tailored%20for%20Kubernetes.), to facilitate the ease of operations and due to this default feature you are able to see your logs in the UI.

If you want to access these logs in a different way you can configure a log server for your kubernetes cluster and you can also store these logs in the persistent volumes as the PV are available even after your pods get deleted.

Comment: I see. Originally, I thought the failed pods are all deleted and I couldn't find them or view the log.  I was wondering why I can check the logs on GCP and was trying to seek if there is other solution. 
But if this is the log server featured by Cloud Provider, this makes sense to me.
Thanks for the response.